# Scoping Differences between variables and objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can someone please explain the difference between these two javascript snippets:

```js
var orange = { prop: "i am simple fruit"};

console.log(orange.prop);  //output: "i am simple fruit"

function go(orange) {
    orange.prop = "Now i have been changed by the function";
};

go(orange);

console.log(orange.prop); // output: "Now i have been changed by the function"
```

.
*In the above block the `go` function obviously changed the `orange` variable/object in the outer scope*
.

```js
var apple = "i am simple apple";

console.log(apple); // output "i am simple apple"

function goApple(apple) {

    apple = "Now i have been changed by the function";

};

goApple(apple);

console.log(apple); // output "i am simple apple"
```

*In this block the outer `apple` variable is unchanged*
I am missing something basic and obvious here, or does javascript have different scoping rules for between variable types?

Comment: This isn't exactly about scoping; it's about variable-passing behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference lies in the type of the argument you pass.

```
typeof apple //"string"
typeof orange //"object"
```

When passing string literals, you're passing immutable data, and it is passed by *value*, hence it cannot change.

EDIT: That is, the data that `window.apple` points to cannot change. The only way to change `window.apple` is to point it to some new data. `window.apple = "something new";`

Comment: While the information here is correct, I think it's also pretty important to note for the OP (@MichaelColeman): immutability means that the string-based `apple` example cannot reproduce the behavior of the object-based `orange` example, but it *is* possible for `orange` example to exhibit the behavior of the `apple ` example, e.g., by `orange = { prop: "totally new object" }`. Primitive immutability means that you can *only* reassign the string variable to a new value (instead of modifying the value) but you can *always* reassign the value of a variable, whether it's a primitive or object.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
function goApple(apple) {
```

defines a function argument which roughly defines a local variable. This is this local variable you're changing, not the external one.

When you do the same with `orange`, you also have a local variable but you're not changing the value of the local variable, only a property of this value (which thus happens to be the same orange object than in the external scope).

Comment: Can the downvoter explain what's wrong in my answer ?

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but maybe because the statement - kind of just repeated what I said in the question, lol.  i.e. Why is it that the property on the orange object in the external scope is changed? thanks

Comment: @MichaelColeman Then I don't know what's not obvious to you. You're changing the property, it's not declared in the local scope.

Comment: yes, I think I what you are saying is that because here: `function go(orange) {
    orange.prop = "Now i.....` the `orange.prop` property is not declared inside the function, and therefore it will be assigned to the `orange` object on the outer scope? I just wondered why `prop` couldn't be defined on the fly inside the function?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript will always pass function parameters by value. 
In the first case you are accessing to a property of an object which is passed by reference. When apple is passed to the function, that reference is copied over to orange. Thus, both refer to the same object in memory

Answer (score 0):

Your question might be a bit clearer if your function arguments had different names from your outer variables. As it is, you're using `apple` and `orange` as global variables and as argument variables, which shadow the outer globals when inside the function.

```
var apple = "i am simple apple";
console.log(apple); // output "i am simple apple"

function goApple(appleArg) {
    appleArg = "Now i have been changed by the function";
};

goApple(apple);
console.log(apple); // output "i am simple apple"
```

Here, you're changing *which* value `appleArg` refers to. This has no effect on which value the outer variable `apple` refers to.

In your `orange` example, you're *modifying the object itself*, not any of the variables that refer to the object.

```
var orange = { prop: "i am simple fruit"};
console.log(orange.prop);  //output: "i am simple fruit"

function go(orangeArg) {
    orangeArg.prop = "Now i have been changed by the function";
};

go(orange);
console.log(orange.prop); // output: "Now i have been changed by the function"
```

here, `orange` and `orangeArg` refer to the same value, and they never change which value they refer to. (In the `apple` example, the `appleArg` variable is changed to refer to a different value than `apple`.) However, the *value itself* changes (so the single value that both variables refer to changes, but neither variable changes *which* value it refers to).

With strings, you can't modify the value itself, because primitives are immutable. With objects, you can modify the properties of the value. Consider a third case where we change which value a variable references:

```
var mango = { prop: "i am simple fruit"};
console.log(mango.prop);  //output: "i am simple fruit"

function go(mangoArg) {
    mangoArg = { prop: "Now i have been changed by the function" };
};

go(mango);
console.log(mango.prop); // output: "i am simple fruit"
```

Here, we changed `mangoArg` in the same way we modified `appleArg`. We made `mangoArg` refer to a *totally new value*, instead of modifying the object referred to by `mango`.

Comment: thanks, I think the answer @AlexanderBrevig gave was a good, quick insight to the *variable passing behaviour* (to borrow your phrase). I think your answer helped with deeper understanding when working with code like this in the future - upvoted just now, thanks